# logging of access to images in image field

Tags: media

If someone hot links an image attached to a node via the image field, does Drupal add a log entry?

I was thinking along the lines of creating a mechanism where I can use images in Drupal nodes to track who reads emails, much like Mailchimp does. If I embed an image hosted by Drupal, would the log show the node as accessed, when an image from the image field was embedded in an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Mail Tracking](https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_tracking) module.

Drupal can only register requests for public files that aren't present yet (e.g. image derivatives that have not yet been created). Otherwise the file will be served directly by the web server.

Comment: awesome! Just what I need.